# How to insert a new value to a set and erase another at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

Each set contains elements in a specified order. I want to specify a bound on the size of a set and *automatically* delete the last element if a new one strictly smaller (in terms of the order) is inserted and the specified size is already reached.

Of course, I could do something like the following:

```
class bounded_set
{
private:
    using set = std::set<Key, Compare, Allocator>;
    using iterator = typename set::iterator;

public:
    bounded_set(std::size_t size)
        : m_size(size)
    { }

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(Key const& value)
    {
        if (m_set.size() < m_size)
            return m_set.insert(value);

        auto last = std::prev(m_set.end());
        if (Compare()(value, *last))
        {
            m_set.erase(last);
            return m_set.insert(value);
        }
        return std::make_pair(last, false);
    }

private:
    set m_set;
    std::size_t m_size;
};
```

Besides the fact, that `bounded_set` is not the best name (since *bounded* containers are a well known thing in the world of concurrent programming), I'm worried about memory allocation in this implementation. Most likely, at first, the space used by `last` will be freed. But immediately after that, new memory needs to be allocated for `value`.

What I really would like to do, is using the memory allocated for `last` and copy over the data for `value` to this place, while preserving the order.

Comment: It's possible you could replace your set with a vector. Unless your dataset is huge and keys have expensive copies without cheap moves, performance will not be impaired and may actually be faster as a vector has less dynamic memory allocations than a set. If you keep your vector sorted, you can use `std::lower_bound` on it for log(n) searches. Of course you'll need to check if vector already holds the value before inserting etc. Wrap this stuff in a "flat_set" class.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your questions correctly, depending on how the underlying data-structure works, that's not necessarily going to be possible without you having to write a custom memory allocator or use one from a library.  For instance, `std::set` uses a red-black tree as the underlying data-structure.  Thus the memory location of the nodes and the relational pointers to-and-from those nodes are intrinsically attached to the total order of the tree.  You can't re-use the memory from a node that is the "least" value and place another value there that is not a new totally-ordered "least" value without also re-sorting all the pointers to that node so that it's in the proper place in the tree for the value of that node.

If you're still concerned about memory usage and want to stick with the STL, rather than `std::set`, maybe you should look into a fixed-length priority-queue or something of that nature that uses an array-based heap as the underlying data-structure so that memory is not constantly allocated and re-allocated for new nodes.

Comment: -1 since entire answer suggests that reusing memory is impossible, but in truth it can be done with a customized allocator.

Comment: Yes, a custom memory allocator would do the trick, and I've changed my answer to reflect that, but it seems needlessly complex when the STL has other tools more readily available, tested, etc ... no?

Comment: MSVC comes with many allocators as does boost.  GCC probably does too.  Meanwhile, using the STL to do this would require a strange combination of vector+sort.  An array-based-heap _may_ be acceptable depending on why he says he needs that particular ordering.  Either way that would have a lot more moves/copies than a `set` would.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of options for you, and a lost opportunity by the standards committee that would have easily solved your problem.

[N3586](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf) proposed a solution to your problem.

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(Key const& value)
{
    if (m_set.size() < m_size)
        return m_set.insert(value);

    auto last = std::prev(m_set.end());
    if (Compare()(value, *last))
    {
        auto temp = m_set.remove(last);
        *temp = value;
        return m_set.insert(temp);
    }
    return std::make_pair(last, false);
}
```

In this hypothetical rewrite, `temp` is a `node_ptr` that allows non-const access to the node's `value_type`.  You can remove the node, write to it, and re-insert it, all without any allocation for nodes.

The committee politely declined this proposal.

A custom allocator for `std::set` could do the trick in a less elegant manner.  Such an allocator would simply cache nodes, and your existing `insert` will just work.  One slight disadvantage with this approach is that while the custom allocator keeps your node from being deallocated, it can not keep your `Key` from being destructed, and then constructed, when you change it.  Some types are more efficient in assignment, than they are in a destruction-construction cycle.  And sometimes the former can be `noexcept` while the latter can not be.

In all, I view the custom allocator approach as a last resort.  You can make it work.  But it takes some carefully planned, and non-intuitive code.

The use of `push_heap`, `pop_heap` comes to mind.  However its use is awkward if you really need an iterator to the inserted or equal element returned.  If you can deal with a void return type, it might look like:

```
void insert(Key const& value)
{
    if (m_set.size() < m_size)
    {
        m_set.push_back(value);
        std::push_heap(m_set.begin(), m_set.end(), Compare{});
    }

    if (Compare()(value, m_set.front()))
    {
        std::pop_heap(m_set.begin(), m_set.end(), Compare{});
        m_set.back() = value;
        std::push_heap(m_set.begin(), m_set.end(), Compare{});
    }
}
```

But it is awkward to search the heap for the newly inserted value, and `push_heap` doesn't provide this information.

Still another option is a sorted vector + insertion sort.  You'll have to write insertion sort yourself, but that is a relatively minor programming task.  The reason you want insertion sort is that you will always be sorting a sorted array except for the last element.  And insertion sort is optimal for this job.

None of these solutions is perfect, and none but [N3586](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf) offer anything approaching a solution "out of the box", i.e. one that doesn't require more than a handful of lines of code.  And [N3586](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf) doesn't exist.  If you think it should exist, contact your C++ national body representative, and tell them so.  Or get involved in the C++ committee yourself, and lobby for it.

Comment: it's a bit mind-boggling why such proposal would be rejected: it seems completely non-intrusive to me. What reasons did the committee give?

Comment: @TemplateRex: There are concerns about how to implement it in a portable manner without invoking undefined behavior. For my money, that is exactly why you put it in the standard library.  The std::lib implementors write non-portable code so that the rest of don't have to (at least not as much). But the committee is made up of many different individuals with many different ideas. It is difficult to even get the best ideas standardized. Move semantics took a decade and was never non-controversial. The key to standardizing `node_ptr` is having someone with the energy and persistence to drive it.